# Java RMI, how should server manage abnormal client shutdown, when it doesn't call any client method?

Tags: java, client, rmi, shutdown

I'm developing a application using Java RMI which enable clients to register topics they want to listen (zero or more) and topic (zero or one) they want to speak about. There is a central server which offers registration service. The communication of clients avoids server with the exception of initial registering of ListenerCallback or SpeakerCallback.
Clients and server work according to Observer pattern.

Callback interfaces:

```
public interface ListenerCallback extends Remote{

void notify(String topic, String msg) throws RemoteException;

} 

public interface SpeakerCallback extends Remote{

Unregister accept(ListenerCallback listenerCallback) throws RemoteException;

}
```

Fragment of registration method on server, both speaker and listener are remote references:

```
for (SpeakerCallback speaker : registeredSpeakers){
    try {
        speaker.accept(listener);
    } catch (RemoteException e){
        //TODO should I unregister speaker?
    }
}
```

As written above in //TODO, I suppose I should unregister speaker from my application registries, because as far as I know RemoteException indicates that the connection with client is broken.

The problem I'm struggling with is how should I manage abnormal client shutdown that only listen to some topic but speak about none. The server holds them in application registries, but has no way to determine whether they are still valid, because it doesn't call its notify() method.

Shoud I add some bogus method to ListenerCallback interface just for trying to determine whether client is still reachable?

Or should I implemented a protocol which would enable clients who speak about (these call notify() method) a certain topic notify server that some listening clients are no more available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for the Remote Session pattern. Every client does a login step, which allocates and returns a new remote object which is really a session object, which in turn:

1. has a `logout()` method, which unexports the object
2. provides the other APIs the client needs, and
3. implements `Unreferenced`, with the `unreferenced()` method calling `logout()`.

So if the client either calls `logout()` or dies the object will disappear; and whatever collateral actions need to happen can all happen in the `logout()` method.

Comment: So far I used a single Register remote object shared by all clients which provided relevant application API. Correct me if I'm wrong, in your solution single Register object is replaced by some LoginService remote object with a login() method which in turn returns a RemoteSession remote object unique for each client?

I believe your solution is what I have been looking for.
Could you recommend any further reading about RemoteSession pattern or distributed systems patterns?

Comment: @Paweł That is exactly correct. I blush to mention that as far as I know I invented and named the Remote Session pattern, in my book on Java RMI, which you can still find second-hand: http://www.amazon.com//gp/offer-listing/0201700433/sr=/qid=/?condition=used&tag=bf-dt-home-20

Answer (score -1):

If you get a remoteException, that does not mean the client is down, you will have to check the sub types of remoteEception like ConnectException etc which inform that there is no endpoint anymore, only then you can unregister the client.

For checking if the clients are alive you can implement some dummy API on the client side and use it for pinging the client in a timer task. You can optimize this ping interval based on the severity of the client registration's staleness.

Comment: The server cannot catch RemoteExceptions that occur when talking to the client, as that happens before the remote method starts or after it returns. Only the client can catch RemoteExceptions.